# How to store array in a cookie and retrieve it back on another page

Tags: jquery

Using jquery, let say I have an array:

**requestedpage.html**

```
var listofinput = "Lionel Messi,30,Argentina";
```

How can i retrieve each of the items in this array on another page? Let say to display it as a text inside a span tag:

**anotherpage.html**

```
Name<span></span>
Age<span></span>
Country<span></span>
```

Comment: You can set the domain of the cookie so that all sites in that domain have access to the same cookies.

Comment: your variable, `listofinput` is not an array -- Comma Separated Value (CSV), but you would simply set the cookie name to something that makes sense (I'm unsure of what this application is doing, so it's hard to say), you would then parse through the cookie data on your second page and pull put the corresponding portions.

Comment: `localStorage` is generally neater than using cookies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage):

```
localStorage.listofinput = listofinput;
```

Then retrieve it with `localStorage.listofinput`:

```
console.log(localStorage.listofinput);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that works for me, where does it store all the array? And is there any way to delete back?

Comment: @RudyReus To delete just say `localStorage.listofinput = undefined`

Comment: @RudyReus It stores it in a window.localStorage object (see the link in my answer)